# Connection name cannot be equal to null or empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Below is my cli command

aws glue create-crawler --name test --role AWSGlueServiceRole-DefaultRole --database-name dev-datalake-glue-zone4-etl-db --targets JdbcTargets=[{ConnectionName="dev-datalake-glue-zone4-etl-connection"},{Path="idm4_prod/%"}] --region us-east-1 --output table

i am getting error
"An error occurred (InvalidInputException) when calling the CreateCrawler operation: Connection name cannot be equal to null or empty."

can anyone please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spotted a potential problem with your `--target` format. `ConnectionName` and `Path` are in two different structures, but they should be in one.

Try

```
aws glue create-crawler --name test --role AWSGlueServiceRole-DefaultRole \
--database-name dev-datalake-glue-zone4-etl-db \
--targets JdbcTargets=[{ConnectionName="dev-datalake-glue-zone4-etl-connection",Path="idm4_prod/%"}] \
--region us-east-1 --output table
```